# Elasticsearch - No node exception after few minutes intermittently

Tags: java, elasticsearch, couchbase

I am using elastic search with java transport client .

Elastic search : **1.1.0**
Java client : **1.1.0**

I am making search query using transport client which works pretty smoothly for sometime. But the problem i am facing is that after some time or few minutes it starts giving me no node available exception on all requests from my java client while the same machine gives me response from curl.

```
Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder().put("client.transport.ping_timeout","50s").build();
client = new TransportClient(settings).addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(host, port));
```

This is how i am connecting with the node .

**Problem**: I am getting no node available exception after some time when we hit it starts giving exception

Also after few mins it again starts giving me response properly

Also I have integrated elasticsearch with couchbase with transport plugin so it also keeps on updating in parallel not heavily but sometimes , can it also be a reason as elastic search also indexes some data from couchbase

Comment: Try to disable Couchbase integration with ElasticSearch to ensure that its not the CB load issue... it its still happening ask ElasticSearch support. I'd imagine CB load can consume all worker threads in ES server so it can't respond to your ES client (but if curl still working while java ES client getting this error then its not it)

Comment: I can't believe ES would be so poorly architected as to allow one data dump process to consume it in its entirety, such that it stops responding. But, stranger things have happened.

Comment: If i add couchbase integration then how will i dump the changes i cannot do it manually and elastic search integration is a very prime functionality to be failing with couchbase it is supported out of the box by both of them. Any Other things you guys can think of i am still trying but out of ideas also , i have used this combination earlier as well but with older versions of the two and it used to work like a charm only wanted to upgrade for some newer functionalities and now i am stuck